# VLC Consuming more amount of CPU - Ubuntu 18.04 | 5.0.0-37-generic | AMD 3800X - Radeon RX5700XT

Tags: vlc, gpu-driver, amdgpu

In my desktop, VLC player consumes almost 30% of a 16 thread processor and I suspect my AMD GPU driver isn't configured properly. Earlier I noticed that latest Radeon Driver 19:50 only installs in 5.0 kernel and hence I had downgraded my kernel version then installed the GPU driver. Still I face issue.

I tried disabling the "hardware accelerated decoding" in VLC preference and noticed the CPU consumption is same as when I enabled it. So I can confirm the GPU isn't being used.

When I tried to load vlc from the terminal, it says that No driver found. I trid Any help on how to proceed further on this issue ? Should I reinstall GPU driver ?

```
rgmani@rgmani:~/jenkins/jenkins_home$ vlc
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 1002:731f, driver (null)
libGL error: No driver found
libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 1002:731f, driver (null)
pci id for fd 5: 1002:731f, driver (null)
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b)
[0000000000af9510] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
libGL error: pci id for fd 20: 1002:731f, driver (null)
libGL error: No driver found
libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
libGL error: pci id for fd 20: 1002:731f, driver (null)
pci id for fd 21: 1002:731f, driver (null)
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
[0000000000b8f100] main playlist: playlist is empty

rgmani@rgmani:~/jenkins/jenkins_home$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic

rgmani@rgmani:~/jenkins/jenkins_home$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for rgmani: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:97 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc900000-fc97ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

EDIT : I installed Kodi Player and that works perfectly fine using very very minimal cpu resourse ( max 3% ) . Seems there is some issue with VLC in recognizing the OpenGL driver of recent AMD Radeon 19:50/ Ubuntu 18.04 combination. If someone resolve it please update. I will mark it as answer and fix my system too.

Comment: As per VLC forums , it is not able to recognize the GL drivers and hence the issue. I have installed Kodi player, it's CPU utilization is 3% only and I am going to settle with it.

Comment: The default player came with Ubuntu 18.04 itself started to work fine after I removed a package. My system is AMD Ryzen processor and AMD 5700XT
sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi